# Нужна помощь. Ошибка в коде

Tags: php, битрикс, синтаксис

После того как внес верстку в битрикс, мне указывает ошибку. Видимо все в том что, я неправильно расположил синтаксис.

> syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) (0)
>   /home/bitrix/ext_www/maz1.webonline.pro/bitrix/templates/.default/components/bitrix/catalog.section.list/main-katalog_maz/template.php:220

Сам код, ниже:

```html
<? case 'LIST':
   echo "";
   $intCurrentDepth = 1;
   $boolFirst = true;
   $Ncols = 1;
   $flag=false;
   foreach ($arResult['SECTIONS'] as &$arSection)
   {
    //print_r($arSection);
    $this->AddEditAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['EDIT_LINK'], $strSectionEdit);
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['DELETE_LINK'], $strSectionDelete, $arSectionDeleteParams);
    if($arSection["UF_INOSTRAN"]!="") $flag=true;
    if($Ncols > 3 and $arSection['DEPTH_LEVEL']!=2)
    {
     echo "";
     $Ncols=1;

    }
    if ($intCurrentDepth < $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL'] && $flag==false)
    {
     if (0 < $intCurrentDepth and $Ncols!=1)
      echo "",str_repeat("", $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL']),'';
    }
    elseif ($intCurrentDepth == $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL'])
    {
     if (!$boolFirst)
     {
      echo '';
      
     }
    }
    else
    {
     while ($intCurrentDepth > $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL'])
     {
      echo '',"",str_repeat("", $intCurrentDepth),'',"",str_repeat("", $intCurrentDepth-1);
      $intCurrentDepth--;
     }
     echo str_repeat("", $intCurrentDepth-1),'';
    }

    echo (!$boolFirst ? "" : ''),str_repeat("", $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL']);
    ?>
    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-catalog">
     <div class="parts-block">
       <?if($arSection['PICTURE']){?>
        <a href="#"><img src="<?=$arSection['PICTURE']['SRC']?>"  class="mx-auto"  alt="<? echo $arSection['PICTURE']['ALT']; ?>" title="<? echo $arSection['PICTURE']['TITLE']; ?>"></a>
       <?} else{?>
      <a href="#"><img src="/bitrix/templates/furniture_pale-blue/img/zagl.jpg"  class="mx-auto"  alt="<? echo $arSection['PICTURE']['ALT']; ?>" title="<? echo $arSection['PICTURE']['TITLE']; ?>"></a>
      <a href="<? echo $arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]; ?>" class="part-header"><? echo $arSection["NAME"];?></a>
        <?;}?>
*/Вот строка 220 (на что жалуется)/*      <?else:?> 
      <? if ($arSection['DEPTH_LEVEL']==2 && $flag==false): ?>
      <p class="parts-description">
       4<a href="<? echo $arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]; ?>"><? echo $arSection["NAME"];?><a/>
      </p>
      <?elseif($flag==false):?>
      <?endif;?>
      <div class="btn-card">
      <a href="#" class="parts-button">Все модели</a>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?
    $intCurrentDepth = $arSection['RELATIVE_DEPTH_LEVEL'];
    $boolFirst = false;
    if($arSection['DEPTH_LEVEL']==1){$Ncols++;}
   }
   unset($arSection);
   while ($intCurrentDepth > 1)
   {
    echo '',"",str_repeat("", $intCurrentDepth),'',"",str_repeat("", $intCurrentDepth-1);
    $intCurrentDepth--;
   }
   if ($intCurrentDepth > 0)
   {
    echo '',"";
   }
   break;
 }
?>
```

Comment: А к какому if у вас этот else - у ближайшего уже есть один

Comment: `<?;}?>` зачем здесь `;`? И насколько я помню должно быть так `<?php } ?>`, если нужно просто что-то вывести, то `<?= $param ?>`. Что делает `:` в данном блоке `<?else:?>`?

Comment: Кто сможет настроить на платной основе? Пишите в whatsapp или телеграмм +79053471089

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить что лишняя последняя закрывающая фигурная скобка "}". 
Но от такого форматирования, глаза вытекают, поэтому не точно. Так-же если вы инклюдите этот файл с кодом в другой, закрывающий тег php не нужен